# PgBouncer server lifetime over

Tags: django, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, pgbouncer

I have setup a django app with `pg_bouncer` and default configuration. Tonight, after 3600 mins the log says:
`2016-05-06 02:45:00.131 6414 LOG S-0x1290330: test/test@127.0.0.1:5432 closing because: server lifetime over (age=3600)`

First question:

- is this normal?
- after this "closing" the django was not able to call the db for a couple of minute.

I'm not an expert, but this seems to be something strange, especially beacuse the db was not available.

PS: this is the output of the stats, is it normal behaviour (not the data, the fact that all the requests seems to not be taken by pgbouncer)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal that pgbouncer closes server connections after the configured server lifetime is over.  That shouldn't affect availability, because there will be other server connections (it's a pool, after all) or new ones will be opened.

If you are seeing a problem, it's probably not related to this.

Comment: that was my feeling. I've to check the settings. One thing is that min connection was set to 1 and then once dropped then there are no other connections. But it seems strange that it takes so long to establish new one. I'll investigate.